# CSP: Criminal Search and Prosecution Problem

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm doing some homework about Artificial Intelligence, and now I'm stuck in this question:

You are a detective in charge of bringing down drug dealers (D). A tip has led you to a small apartment complex where you believe one or more D might be hiding out. There are five apartments in a row. Each apartment could contain a drug dealer D or could contain innocent people: adults (A), families with babies (B), or with teenagers (T). Before you break down a door, you need to be absolutely sure that a dealer D is inside, otherwise you could get sued for police suboptimality.

[image: this is the diagram for the problem]

To help you narrow down where drug dealers D might be (if any are there at all!), you use the fact that different people make different noises. Every time you walk between two apartments, you can hear the louder of the two noises that are being made in those apartments. The loudest people are teenagers T, who blast music (m), the next loudest are babies B who cry (c), the next loudest is the drug dealer D, who makes a rustling sound (r), and the quietest people are adults A, who are totally silent (s). For example, if there were a baby in one house and a teenager in next, you would hear music (m) when standing between those apartments. Walking by the five apartments, you hear the noises shown in the diagram above. You decide to try solving this problem as a CSP

The question made me confused is: List all solutions to this CSP or state that none exist.
I assumed that my answer is correct, which is:

```
1T
2B
3A
4A
5T
```

but the correct answer I found is:

```
1T
2B
3D
4A
5T
```

and

```
1T
2B
3D
4D
5T
```

and

```
1T
2B
3A
4D
5T
```

I think maybe I didn't get the question correctly. So anyone can explain this to me, which one is correct?

Comment: pretty sure we need the diagram

Comment: I have just update it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is deductive logic, not a programming problem.  AI does not enter into the solution space.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract way to look at this is to see what can you eliminate from each house.  You know you can hear the loudest noise between houses which means one or both of the houses on either side of the noise could contain that noise maker.  So in paragraph form:

Between 1 & 2 is music so 1 and 2 might each contain a Teen and that is all we know.

Between 2 & 3 is crying so we know 2 does not contain anything louder than crying (music) so 2 cannot contain a T, therefore 1 must contain the Teen.

Between 3 & 4 is rustling so we know 3 or 4 might contain a Dealer.  We also now know nothing louder than rustling exists in 3, therefore 2 must contain a Baby.

Between 4 & 5 is music so now we have a problem.  We know 5 must contain a Teen, otherwise music would have been louder than rustling and we would not have heard rustling between 3 & 4.  However, now all we know about 3 & 4 is that they might contain anything as quiet or quieter than a Dealer, and also that at least one must contain a dealer.  So those combinations are [A, D], [D, D], [D, A].

That gives us a set of final answers [T, B, A, D, T] or [T, B, D, D, T] or [T, B, D, A, T]

Comment: The way I understand the problem is so far like exactly what you say, but what makes I confused is the phrase "none exist" in "List all solutions to this CSP or state that none exist.", what does it mean in the problem?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be asking you if you can proceed with entering a house.  It is asking you if using the described logic, can you narrow down the set of possibilities.  I would imagine "none exist" would mean you cannot narrow anything down, i.e. m between all houses tells you nothing about Dealers.  I think what we have done is step 1 of a multi-step process and more must be done to actually enter a house.  The question is worded weird and confusing for sure.  It should have clearly defined what a "solution" is.